# Why is no SignalR hub method being called from the client?

Tags: c#, typescript, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

There's a hub:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using RemoteMaster.Server.Abstractions;

namespace RemoteMaster.Server.Hubs;

public class ControlHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IScreenCasterService _streamingService;
    private readonly IViewerService _viewerService;
    private readonly ILogger<ControlHub> _logger;

    public ControlHub(ILogger<ControlHub> logger, IScreenCasterService streamingService, IViewerService viewerService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _streamingService = streamingService;
        _viewerService = viewerService;
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        await _streamingService.StartStreaming(Context.ConnectionId, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }

    public async Task SetQuality(int quality)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Invoked SetQuality");

        _viewerService.SetImageQuality(quality);
    }
}
```

ViewerService:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using RemoteMaster.Server.Abstractions;
using RemoteMaster.Shared.Options;
using SkiaSharp;

namespace RemoteMaster.Server.Services;

public class ViewerService : IViewerService
{
    private readonly IOptionsSnapshot<ViewerOptions> _options;

    public ViewerService(IOptionsSnapshot<ViewerOptions> options)
    {
        _options = options;
    }

    public SKEncodedImageFormat GetImageFormat()
    {
        return _options.Value.ImageFormat switch
        {
            "Png" => SKEncodedImageFormat.Png,
            "Jpeg" => SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg,
            _ => SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg,
        };
    }

    public int GetImageQuality()
    {
        return _options.Value.ImageQuality ?? 80;
    }

    public void SetImageQuality(int quality)
    {
        if (quality < 1 || quality > 100)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Quality must be between 1 and 100.");
        }

        _options.Value.ImageQuality = quality;
    }
}
```

And the client:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

namespace RemoteMaster.Client.Pages;

public partial class Control
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Host { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    private IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

    private string _screenDataUrl;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            var dotnetHelper = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("window.setupSignalRConnection", Host, dotnetHelper);
        }
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public async Task UpdateScreenDataUrl(string url)
    {
        _screenDataUrl = url;
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    public async Task QualityChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var quality = int.Parse(e.Value.ToString());
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("window.setQuality", quality);
    }
}
```

--

```
@page "/{Host}/control"

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_screenDataUrl))
{
    <img src="@_screenDataUrl" width="1494" onload="window.revokeUrl(this.src)" />
    <div>
        <label for="qualityInput">Quality: </label>
        <input id="qualityInput" type="number" min="1" max="100" @onchange="QualityChanged" />
    </div>
}
else
{
    <p>Establishing connection...</p>
}
```

--

```
import { HubConnectionBuilder, LogLevel, HttpTransportType } from '@microsoft/signalr'
import { MessagePackHubProtocol } from '@microsoft/signalr-protocol-msgpack'

declare global {
  interface Window {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    setupSignalRConnection: (host: string, dotnetHelper: any) => void
    setQuality: (quality: number) => void
  }
}

interface ScreenUpdateDto {
  Data: Uint8Array
  IsEndOfImage: boolean
}

let _buffer: Uint8Array[] = []
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
let connection: any

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
window.setupSignalRConnection = function (host: string, dotnetHelper: any) {
  connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(`http://${host}:5076/hubs/control`, {
      skipNegotiation: true,
      transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets
    })
    .withAutomaticReconnect([0, 3000, 5000, 10000, 15000, 30000])
    .withHubProtocol(new MessagePackHubProtocol())
    .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
    .build()

  connection.on('ScreenUpdate', (dto: ScreenUpdateDto) => {
    _buffer.push(dto.Data)

    if (dto.IsEndOfImage) {
      const blob = new Blob(_buffer, { type: 'image/jpeg' })
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      dotnetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('UpdateScreenDataUrl', url)
      _buffer = []
    }
  })

  connection.start().catch((err: Error) => { console.error(err.toString()) })
}

window.setQuality = function (quality) {
  console.log('SetQuality on client Invoked')
  console.log('Connection state: ' + connection.state)

  connection.invoke('SetQuality', quality)
}
```

The thing is that if I call SetQuality in the hub for example in OnInitializedAsync then everything will work, StartStreaming works the same way. But if I call this method as I do in the attached code, it is not called at all (I make this conclusion because there is no _logger.LogInformation("Invoked SetQuality") output);

And in general, any method I create is not called from the client, but it is called from the server.

This may be a trivial task, but I'm completely confused.

P.S.

There is nothing at all in the developer console.

```
[2023-07-10T15:08:24.323Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'http://localhost:5254/_blazor'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2023-07-10T15:08:24.363Z] Information: WebSocket connected to ws://localhost:5254/_blazor?id=LOTbr86UsoQ2D51sxnldmw.
bundle.js:253 [2023-07-10T15:08:24.405Z] Information: WebSocket connected to ws://127.0.0.1:5076/hubs/control.
bundle.js:253 [2023-07-10T15:08:24.405Z] Information: Using HubProtocol 'messagepack'.
```

The only thing is that when changing the quality you can see that it is logged BUT `connection.invoke` is not called

```
bundle.js:4030 SetQuality on client Invoked
bundle.js:4031 Connection state: Connected
```

Comment: I check the client code, it should be working. Could you share the logs in browser develop tools.

Comment: @JasonPan, I've added everything in the developer console to the question

Comment: if you could share the screenshot, it would be better.

Comment: from the logs you shared, seems there are two connections in your blazor application. Please define the signalr connection name `signalr_connection`, then invoke the method you want.

Comment: `bundle.js:4030 SetQuality on client Invoked` seems from `5254`. pls let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @JasonPan, 5254 is the `Blazor Server` client application.
And 5076 is a server application located on a remote PC. When creating a connection I just specify `.withUrl(`http://${host}:5076/hubs/control`). And on the server (5076) just located the hub method of which I call in connection.invoke

Comment: in this case, both client and server are running on the same PC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254429/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-vitkuz573).